# Unicode strlen equivalent in MFC

Tags: unicode, mfc, strlen

Consider the following simple code:

```
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EName,LPTSTR(cName),11);

k=strlen(cName);
```

I want to get the length of String that user puts at edit box but I have
the wrong result K=1 (always) because it's unicode string and it get
the first character and the second is null and I donot know how to fix it.
Any comment is welcome.
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the string, or more accurately the amount of *characters* (not bytes) copied to the output buffer is returned by your call to `GetDlgItemText()`.

You can also check the length of the string directly. Since you use ANSI/Unicode compatible macros such as `LPTSTR`, you should use a ANSI/Unicode compatible strlen function: [_tcslen(cName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

`_tcslen()` resolves to `strlen()` when compiling to ANSI/MBCS and to `wcslen()` when compiling to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wcslen()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Of course you could just do:

```
k = GetDlgItemText(IDC_EName,LPTSTR(cName),11);
```

since the return value specifies the number of characters copied to the buffer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx